# check whether user granted Clipboard permisssion or not?

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, permissions, clipboard

How to check whether user has granted clipboard read permisssion or not using javascript?

I am trying to get as a boolean value indicating the current clipboard permission status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if you have permission to access the clipboard using the [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions):

```
await navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'clipboard-read' });
// or 'clipboard-write' for permission to write

// sample result: {state: 'granted'}
```

Comment: For TypeScript, it should be `{ name: 'clipboard-read' as PermissionName }`, otherwise it shows an error.

Comment: Indeed, seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1245) in TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator

Answer (score 2):

The clipboard read permission has 3 states: granted, denied, or prompt "neither denied or nor granted".

Therefore, your code should look something like:

```
const queryOpts = { name: 'clipboard-read', allowWithoutGesture: false };
const permissionStatus = await navigator.permissions.query(queryOpts);
// Will be 'granted', 'denied' or 'prompt':
console.log(permissionStatus.state);

// Listen for changes to the permission state
permissionStatus.onchange = () => {
  console.log(permissionStatus.state);
};
```

code citation: https://web.dev/async-clipboard/

So from the code above, you can write a function that returns true or false like:

```
// you pass permissionStatus.state to this function
const checkClipboardPermission = (state) => {
    if(state == "granted"){
        return true;
    }
    else if(state == "denied"){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```